# Is CNOT a one-qubit or two-qubit operation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

Is [CNOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled_NOT_gate) a one-qubit or two-qubit operation? It has inputs of two qubits and needs two quantum wires.

Comment: What is a "quantum wire"?

Comment: Have you looked at the Wikipedia entry that Qmechanic added?

Comment: @DanielSank: a quantum wire is a theoretical abstraction which conveys qubits between quantum gates without altering their phase relative to other qubits. Strictly speaking you can view a quantum-logic circuit on $N$ qubits as $m$ columns of operations that are $N$ squares high each tiled with some $1\times p$ polyomino "gates". Some of these "gates" will however be swaps and some will be no-ops; the "wires" allow us to visualize those things much more easily. (They are also combined with a relaxation of the polyomino-adjacency for "controlled" gates, but that's kind of a minor point.)

Comment: @ChrisDrost I figured that's what OP meant, but having been in quantum computation for eight years I would say that's not standard terminology and OP should be more descriptive.

Comment: @Daniel That seems like a pretty unambiguous term and a pretty easy place to end up as a beginner. They [*look*](https://www.google.com/search?q=quantum+gate&tbm=isch) exactly the same way as wires in a circuit diagram, after all.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Again, it came across weirdly to me and I've been in the field for eight years, so I doubt it's standard. As for whether or not its ambiguous, well yeah, sort of. I wasn't sure if OP had some hardware implementation in mind.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos Yes but it does not say anything about it being a two-qubit operation. I have a doubt about it being a one-qubit operation.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Quantum wires are quasi-1D systems such as carbon nanotubes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_wire

Answer (score 4):

It's therefore a two-qubit operation.

Comment: So inputs of n qubits = n-qubit operation? In that sense, can I say that Toffoli gate and Fredkin gate are three-qubit operations?

Answer (score -1):

I saw your another question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/211696/where-is-the-one-qubit-operation-in-this-graph). It is related. CNOT gate as an entity is a two-qubit operation for sure. If you really want to go into the `picky` level, it can also be treated as a combination of two one-qubit operations which may not be separable in the physical sense.

Comment: "a combination of two one-qubit operations which may not be separable in the physical sense."??

Comment: Thank you Xiaodong Qi. Only one qubit (target qubit) is operated (by the X-gate).