# Where is the one-qubit operation in this graph?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

[image]

Where is the one-qubit operation on right subfigure of Fig 4.8?

Answer (score -1):

At a glance all gates on the right subfigure are *two-qubit gates*. In literature, sometimes people usually refer a *two-qubit gate* to be a combination of one-qubit operations (like the V operations) and two-qubit operations (the one-qubit operations plus the control part), to my understanding. So, any operations connected to a circuit line can be viewed as one-qubit operation in this sense.

Comment: CNOT may be meant to be the one-qubit operation by the author.